# Python script as a cron job - how to format the output as an e-mail with attachments?

Tags: python, email, cron, attachment, email-attachments

Since Cron can mail output of its commands to the user, I decided to use it in my project. I quickly realized that I could really use a way to attach files to the generated e-mails. I read in Cron's documentation that you can change Content-Type of its e-mails to multipart/mixed, which is necessary for sending attachments. How can I write a Python script that, when ran as a Cron job with e-mail notifications turned on, would send its stdout to message body and attach any files I find appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your crontab:

```
CONTENT_TYPE='multipart/mixed; boundary="------------040907050602020300000601"'
```

Now, the script that prints "Hello world" in the message body and attaches /etc/redhat-release would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import sys
import StringIO
import atexit

# Back up stdout and stderr. We'll overwrite them by StringIO to save the
# output to a string.
stdout_copy = sys.stdout
stderr_copy = sys.stderr

f = StringIO.StringIO()

sys.stdout = f
sys.stderr = f

# The MIME message we're going to wrap the program's output in.
msg = MIMEMultipart()

# This is the boundary I set in my crontab file. Kludgy, but I knew no other
# way to send multipart files from cron. To reproduce it, add the following
# to your crontab:
#
# CONTENT_TYPE='multipart/mixed; boundary="------------040907050602020300000601"'

msg.set_boundary('------------040907050602020300000601')


# At exit, print f's contents as a MIME message.
def flush_f():

    # Rewind the f StringIO so that f.read() will read all the data.
    f.seek(0)

    # Restore stdout and stderr - this will let us print to the program's
    # standard output. Note that we overwrite stderr with the stdout - this
    # will let us see the error messages in crontab e-mails.
    sys.stdout = stdout_copy
    sys.stderr = stdout_copy

    # Add the stdout contents to the message body.
    stdout_contents = MIMEText(f.read(), "plain")
    msg.attach(stdout_contents)

    # Attach the attachments. We use "unknown" to trick Thunderbird into
    # thinking that the file is binary.
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(".png"):
            attachment = MIMEBase("image", "png")
        else:
            attachment = MIMEBase("application", "unknown")
        attachment.set_payload(open(filename).read())
        attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment',
                              filename=filename)
        encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
        msg.attach(attachment)

    # Print the final message.
    print(msg.as_string())
atexit.register(flush_f)

print("Hello, world!")
filenames = ["/etc/redhat-release"]
```